# Strict equal inside of array

Tags: javascript, chai

I want to check that two arrays contain the same elements (not deep equals) in the same order.

```
var a = { id: 1 }
var b = { id: 2 }
var c = { id: 3 }

var arr = [a, b, c]

expect(arr).to.______([a, b, c])               // true

expect(arr).to.______([a, c, b])               // false: different order
expect(arr).to.______([a, b])                  // false: missing element
expect(arr).to.______([a, b, c, { id: 4 }])    // false: extra element
expect(arr).to.______([a, b, { id: 3 }])       // false: different object reference
```

Of course I can write

```
assert.strictEqual(arr.length, expected.length, "length");
for (let q = 0; q < arr.length; ++q) assert.strictEqual(arr[q], expected[q], `[${q}]`);
```

But I think there should be some method for that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`.ordered`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_ordered) in conjunction with [`.members`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members), like this:

> By default, members are compared using strict (===) equality. Add .deep earlier in the chain to use deep equality instead.

```js
const expect = chai.expect;

const a = 1;
const b = 2;
const c = 3;

const input = [a, b, c];

expect(input).to.have.ordered.members([a, b, c]);
expect(input).to.not.have.ordered.members([b, a, c]);
expect(input).to.not.have.ordered.members([a, c, b]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/4.2.0/chai.min.js"></script>
```